# Why does emplace take an iterator instead of a const_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I'm using clang 3.4-1ubuntu3. When I try to call `std::vector::emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args)`, I get the error

```
my_file.hpp:86:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'emplace'
                store.emplace(pos, args...);
                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
...
/usr/include//c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:958:9: note: candidate function ... not viable: no known
      conversion from '__normal_iterator<const_pointer, [...]>' to '__normal_iterator<pointer, [...]>' for 1st argument
        emplace(iterator __position, _Args&&... __args);
        ^
```

But according to cppreference, [`std::vector::emplace` takes a const_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace). What's going on here?

Comment: I think cppreference is wrong here. Using a `const_iterator` for `emplace` doesn't seem to make an awful lot of sense.

Comment: @Cubic According to the Standard, `std::vector::emplace` does indeed take a `const_iterator`. (Which makes sense; the other mutating member functions take `const_iterator`s too. After all, you're not using the iterator *itself* in a non-const context, just the vector.)

Comment: @Sneftel Huh, interesting. I misunderstood how that worked then. Thanks.

Comment: @Cubic After all, you already have a *mutable* reference to the vector. It makes no sense to also require a mutable iterator.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a bug in the compiler (or, more accurately, the standard library). According to the standard (§23.3.6.1) the signature should be:

```
template <class... Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator position, Args&&... args);
```

Comment: @Angew: Just because OP is compiling with clang doesn't mean it is not using the standard library which comes with g++. In fact, the error shows `/usr/include//c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:958` as the location of the error, which is certainly in the Gnu standard library.

Comment: @rici Also called libstdc++

Comment: @Columbo: I was trying to avoid using that name because it is would still be necessary to explain which library that is, since for many people the correspondence GNU<->libstdc++ and Clang<->libc++ is non-obvious.